# How to create an alias of Cyrillic character with leading backslash?

Tags: macros, xetex, cyrillic, alias

`RUN: xelatex book.tex`

```
\documentclass[a5paper,12pt]{book}
\usepackage[X2,T2A,OT2]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english,russian]{babel}
\usepackage{marvosym}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{xunicode,xltxtra,url,parskip}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}

\usepackage{supertabular}           
\usepackage{titlesec}
\newpagestyle{mystyle}{\setfoot[\thepage][][]{}{}{\thepage}}
\pagestyle{mystyle}

% \defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text}
% \setmainfont{OldStandard}[
%              Extension=.otf,
%              UprightFont=*-Regular,
%              ItalicFont=*-Italic,
%              BoldItalicFont =*-BoldItalic,
%              BoldFont=*-Bold
% ]
\newcommand{\И}{{\fontencoding{X2}\selectfont\CYRII}} % І
\newcommand{\и}{{\fontencoding{X2}\selectfont\cyrii}} % і
\newcommand{\Е}{{\fontencoding{X2}\selectfont\CYRYAT}} % Ѣ
\newcommand{\е}{{\fontencoding{X2}\selectfont\cyryat}} % ѣ
\newcommand{\Ф}{{\fontencoding{X2}\selectfont\CYROTLD}} % Ө
\newcommand{\ф}{{\fontencoding{X2}\selectfont\cyrotld}} % ө
\newcommand{\Ы}{{\fontencoding{X2}\selectfont\CYRIZH}} % Ѵ
\newcommand{\ы}{{\fontencoding{X2}\selectfont\cyrizh}} % ѵ

\usepackage[absolute]{textpos}
\begin{document}

\И \и \Е \е \Ф \ф \Ы \ы         % IT WORKS with trailing space!
Нар\еч\ие                       % Нарѣчіе, ERROR: Undefined control sequence.

\end{document}
```

Why aliases `\И` `\и`, and etc do not work without trailing space?
Is it possible to create such kind of alias?

Comment: Don't use fontencodings like X2 or T2A with xelatex

Comment: LaTeX considers all characters until the next non-letter as part of the command, so it is looking for the command `\еч` followed by the command `\ие`, which are both undefined. LaTeX is not smart enough to check if there are shorter alternatives if a longer command is not defined (which would make the implementation of the parser much more complex). The space is disregarded when parsing, so the output should be ok when you use `Нар\е ч\и е` or alternatively `Нар\е{}ч\и{}е`. But don't do that - XeLaTeX is not designed to use the older fontencodings as @UlrikeFischer said.

Comment: xelatex is designed to use Unicode fonts but with `\usepackage[X2,T2A,OT2]{fontenc}` you are forcing legacy 8 and 7 bit encodings so losing almost all the benefits of xetex and making it impossible to get correct hyphenation. It is recommended not to use either `xunicode` or `xltxtra` with current xelatex as well.

Answer (score 2):

You're looking for complications. Here's a working version, *provided* you use a font with the required glyphs.

```latex
\documentclass[a5paper,12pt]{book}
\usepackage[english,russian]{babel}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\setmainfont{OldStandard}[
  Extension=.otf,
  UprightFont=*-Regular,
  ItalicFont=*-Italic,
  BoldItalicFont =*-BoldItalic,
  BoldFont=*-Bold
]

\begin{document}

И и Е е Ф ф Ы ы 

Наречие

Нарѣчіе

\end{document}
```

[image]

The package `fontenc` may be used, but in very special cases. Don't load `xunicode` nor `xltxtra`.

If you are not able to easily input the ancient characters, you could do something like

```
\newcommand{\И}{І}
```

but then `\И` should be followed by a space, unless you change the category code of `И` (which might be dangerous). If you like to be bold,

```
\newcommand{\И}{І} \catcode`И=12
```

(and similarly for the other characters) might do.

I'd prefer a different approach, namely to define `\?` that looks for the following character and takes the appropriate action. The list is easily extendable to other combinations.

```latex
\documentclass[a5paper,12pt]{book}
\usepackage[english,russian]{babel}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\setmainfont{OldStandard}[
  Extension=.otf,
  UprightFont=*-Regular,
  ItalicFont=*-Italic,
  BoldItalicFont =*-BoldItalic,
  BoldFont=*-Bold
]

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\?}{m}
 {
  \str_case:nnF { #1 }
   {
    {И}{І} {и}{і}
    {Е}{Ѣ} {е}{ѣ}
    {Ф}{Ѳ} {ф}{ѳ}
    {Ы}{Ѵ} {ы}{ѵ}
   }
   {??}
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\?И\?и\?Е\?е\?Ф\?ф\?Ы\?ы

Наречие

Нарѣчіе

Нар\?еч\?ие

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Does OldStandard have BoldItalic?

Comment: @OlegLobachev The version I have (TeX Live 2019) does.

Comment: I want to insert \ just before Cyrillic letters и, е or ф
because there are no і ѣ, Ө and ѵ on standard keyboard.

Comment: @111 OK, I added some suggestions.

Comment: @egreg Thank you a lot!
But form of FITA is not appropriate.
Is is better to use
\newcommand{\Ф}{{\fontencoding{X2}\selectfont\CYROTLD}} % Ө

Comment: @egreg Oh, I see. `This is the README for the OldStandard package, version 2.5,
reease 2020-02-26. [...]
In comparison to previous releases of *Old Standard*, this release 
includes a bold italic, new letters and some corrections`.